# How to Wait for the element to be found since the difference in Page load time

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests, testng

I am working on testing a ecommerce site and i have a script running in selenium using testng framework. Sometimes the script works fine and some time since the page loads slower and it shows no element found. What should i be doing to optimize the current code?? Any help

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebDriverWait

It will wait till particular condition is satisfied. Below code will wait until element is visible:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("some-valid-element-id"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its good practice to use page load time out wherever you are navigating to new web page.
it will wait till all the element gets loaded or till 40 sec. so basically it will check for two conditions

1. till all elements to be loaded
2. till 40 sec. (you can give time as per your requirement)

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
>   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);